# Creative use of burning and dodging

Tags: photo-editing

Exactly how can we use burning and dodging to to isolate the subject and create strong points of interest in a photograph ?
There are a lot of Internet articles on how to dodge and burn but they do not explain about its creative usage to direct the viewers eye
Thank you

Comment: You might also be interested in reading http://petapixel.com/2013/09/12/marked-photographs-show-iconic-prints-edited-darkroom/ and the article linked in there https://theliteratelens.com/2012/02/17/magnum-and-the-dying-art-of-darkroom-printing/ about Pablo Iniro's darkroom work for Magnum, it may give you a good idea about how a master printer planned his dodging and burning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With some knowledge of composition and design the photographer can lead viewer's eye through the image. Dodging and burning can be used to subtly emphasize elements of composition. For example, you can make the main elements of design a bit lighter and suppress others by darkening them. An excellent book about composition and design is The Photographer's Eye: [Composition and Design for Better Digital Photos](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0240809343) by Michael Freeman.

One does not have to take any sophisticated and educated approaches to benefit from dodging and burning. The most basic form is probably darkening corners and outer edges to bring viewer's attention into the center. The technique is also used to tame overly bright parts of the image that attract most attention, but do not have any significance in the message the author is attempting to convey.

There are other creative uses in portrait photography, landscape photography and elsewhere.